# Is the compiler allowed to optimize the stack memory usage by reordering local variables?

Tags: c, stack, alignment, compiler-optimization

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void some_func(char*, int*, char*);

void stack_alignment(void) {
    char a = '-';
    int i = 1337;
    char b = '+';
    some_func(&a, &i, &b); // to prevent the compiler from removing the local variables
    printf("%c|%i|%c", a, i, b);
}
```

It generates the following assembly (comments added by myself, I'm a complete newbie to assembly):

```
$ vim stack-alignment.c
$ gcc -c -S -O3 stack-alignment.c
$ cat stack-alignment.s
        .file   "stack-alignment.c"
        .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
        .ascii "%c|%i|%c\0"
        .text
        .p2align 2,,3
        .globl  _stack_alignment
        .def    _stack_alignment;       .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_stack_alignment:
LFB7:
        .cfi_startproc
        subl    $44, %esp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
        movb    $45, 26(%esp)    // local variable 'a'
        movl    $1337, 28(%esp)  // local variable 'i'
        movb    $43, 27(%esp)    // local variable 'b'
        leal    27(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
        leal    28(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        leal    26(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _some_func
        movsbl  27(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
        movl    28(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
        movsbl  26(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    $LC0, (%esp)
        call    _printf
        addl    $44, %esp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
LFE7:
        .def    _some_func;     .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .def    _printf;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
```

As you can see there are 3 local variables (`a`, `i` and `b`) with the sizes of 1 byte, 4 byte and 1 byte. Including the padding this would be 12 byte (assuming the compiler aligns to 4 bytes).

Wouldn't it be more memory efficient if the compiler would change the order of the variables to (`a`, `b`, `i`)? Then only 8 bytes would be necessary.

Here a "graphic" representation:

```
    3 bytes unused                  3 bytes unused
     vvvvvvvvvvv                     vvvvvvvvvvv
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a |   |   |   | i             | b |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

                |
                v

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b |   |   | i             |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
         ^^^^^^^
      2 bytes unused
```

Is the compiler allowed to do this optimization (by the C standard etc.)?

- If no (as I think the assembly output shows), why?
- If yes, why doesn't that happen above?

Comment: Assuming it is allowed by standards etc, then it would be completely up to the individual compiler implementation whether they do it or not. I'd imagine it would be controlled by optimization levels at compile time.

Comment: The compiler/optimizer is free to place locals wherever it wishes, as long as it does not break the program. It's free to place two variables in the same place if it is certain they're never used at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried to compile with different optimization options? Perhaps you have compiled with the optimizations off.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `-Os`? With `O3` you tell the compiler to use optimisations that will make the code larger, if it makes it faster.

Comment: I think compiler is already optimizing the memory space . From the assembly code:  `a`, `b` and `i` will be at address 26(%esp), 27(%esp) and 28(%esp).

Comment: Any discussion about optimization is completely pointless without a specific system in mind. I'm trying to read the OP's mind... hmm... this is a Linux or Windows system on a 32 bit Intel x86 derivate.

Comment: @Lundin It's Windows 64 bit on an Intel Core i5 with MinGW gcc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the compiler allowed to do this optimization (by the C standard etc.)?

Yes.

> If yes, why doesn't that happen above?

It did happen.

Read the assembler output carefully.

```
    movb    $45, 26(%esp)    // local variable 'a'
    movl    $1337, 28(%esp)  // local variable 'i'
    movb    $43, 27(%esp)    // local variable 'b'
```

Variable `a` is at offset 26.
Variable `b` is at offset 27.
Variable `i` is at offset 28.

Using the images you made the layout is now:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | a | b | i             |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 ^^^^^^^
 2 bytes unused
```

Comment: I really didn't notice the number in the second argument of the mov(l|b) command >.<, thank you for that. Well, still funny why gcc arranges these commands in this order, it would have been easier to notice if it were the other way around.

Comment: No idea why the instructions are ordered that way. If I had to speculate either it is something about two `movb` instructions touching the same memory word that could stall (although we have store buffers for a reason, so this is unlikely) or more likely: it doesn't matter, so they were generated in the order the compiler happened to have them in the internal syntax tree.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is free to layout the local variables as it wants. It need not even use the stack.

It can store the local variables in an order unrelated to the order of declaration on the stack if it uses the stack.

> Is the compiler allowed to do this optimization (by the C standard etc.)?
>
> - If yes, why doesn't that happen above?

Well, is it an optimisation at all?

That's not clear. It uses a couple of bytes less, but that rarely matters. But on some architectures, it may be faster to read a `char` if it is stored word-aligned. So then putting the `char`s next to each other would force one of them at least to not be word-aligned and make reading it slower.

Comment: This does not fully answer the question. A couple of bytes on the call stack can matter when implementing a recursive algorithm. C is the language of systems programming, so saving memory where possible *is* a concern. The question is whether GCC is missing out on an optimization opportunity or is choosing one side of a tradeoff. It is almost certainly true that on *some* architectures it's faster to read a `char` from an aligned location; but the assembly is generated for a concrete architecture. If this architecture does not impose a penalty for unaligned reads, the optimization is missing.

Answer (score 2):

> Wouldn't it be more memory efficient if the compiler would change the order of the variables

There is no way to tell without talking about a specific CPU, a specific OS and a specific compiler. In general, the compiler does optimally. In order to optimize code in a meaningful way, you need in-depth knowledge about the specific system.

In your case, the compiler is likely set to optimize for speed in this case. It seems that the compiler has decided that aligned addresses for every variable gives the most efficient code. On some systems it is not just faster, but also mandatory to allocate at even addresses, because some CPUs can only handle aligned access.

> Is the compiler allowed to do this optimization (by the C standard etc.)?

Yes, the C standard doesn't even require the variables to be allocated. The compiler is completely free to handle this in any way it wants and it does not need to document how or why. It can allocate the variables anywhere, it could optimize them away entirely, or allocate them inside CPU registers, or on the stack, or in a little wooden box underneath your desk.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in normal systems where speed matters, reading word wise is faster than reading character wise. The memory loss compared to the speed gain is ignored. But in case of the system where memory matters, like in different cross compilers which generate executable (in a very generic meaning) for a particular target platform, the picture might be entirely different. Compiler can pack them together, even check their lifetime and uses, depending on that reduce the bitwidth, etc etc. So basically it's highly dependent on the necessity. But in general every compiler gives you the flexibility if you want to `"pack"` them tightly. You can look into manual for that

Answer (score 0):

Compilers with buffer overflow protection for the stack (`/GS` for Microsoft's compiler) can reorder variables as a security feature. For example, if your local variables are some constant size char array (buffer) and a function pointer, an attacker that can overflow the buffer could also overwrite the function pointer. Thus, the local variables are reordered such that the buffer is next to the canary. This way, an attacker can not (directly) compromise the function pointer and the buffer overflow is (hopefully) detected by the destroyed canary.

Warning: Such features do not prevent compromise, they just raise the barriers for an attacker, but a skilled attacker normally finds its way around.